# Comando linux para borrar ficheros con una antiguedad de 7 dias o superior

Tags: linux, bash, script, consola, debian

Tengo esta estructura de directorios
/home/cgallardo/backups/local

- www
- mysql

La carpeta www dentro solo tiene archivos rar, por ejemplo www-06-04-01.zip, en cambio la carpeta mysql tiene carpetas dentro por ejemplo
/mysql/copia-05-04-2021/, /mysql/copia-06-04-2021, ....

Y dentro de cada carpeta mysql existen archivos, por ejemplo

/mysql/copia-05-04-2021/tabla1.sql.gz

/mysql/copia-05-04-2021/tabla2.sql.gz

...

Lo que intento hacer es buscar aquellos archivos con una antiguedad superior a 7 dias y eliminarlos, con la carpeta www me funciona, pero con la carpeta mysql que dentro tiene directorios no me funciona me dice este error.

Me gustaria que elimine aquellos directorios dentro de la carpeta MYSQL que tengan una antiguedad > 7 dias

rm: cannot remove '/home/cgallardo/backups/local/mysql': Is a directory

**Comando que ejecuto**

find /home/cgallardo/backups/local/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} ;

Comment: añade `-type f` para que solo busque ficheros. Está intentando eliminar un directorio.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, me gustaria que elimine aquellos directorios dentro de la carpeta MYSQL que tengan una antiguedad > 7 dias

Comment: Para borrar un directorio, una de dos: o está vacío y con `rmdir` ya funciona, o tiene contenido y debes añadir `-f` para que borre su contenido. ¿En cuál de los casos estás?

Comment: Estoy en el caso, que el directorio tendrá contenido, vuelvo a editar la pregunta principal. gracias

Comment: Pero una duda: ¿lo que quieres comprobar que es más antiguo que 7 días son los ficheros del directorio o el directorio en sí? Por lo que entiendo, querrás borrar todo lo que haya dentro, por lo que debes ir con cuidado de no eliminar de más.

Comment: pero si es uno/varios directorios, entonces para borrarlo debes utilizar `rm -rf` (recursivo y forzado). sino, no puedes borrar un directorio si este tiene contenido. Pero como te dicen, ten cuidado. El hecho de que el directorio este creado hace 7 dias, no significa que el contenido no sea mas actual... podrias tener archivos de hace 2 dias dentro de un directorio que fue creado hace 2 años...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se puede hacer de la siguiente manera.

> find /home/cgallardo/backups/local/mysql -mtime -7 -type f | xargs rm -rf

Esto lo que hace es buscar ficheros dentro del directorio con una fecha de creación mayor o igual a 7 dias, esos valores devueltos los elimina directaemnte.

Antes de ejecutarlo todo comprueba a mano si es correcto lo que te devuelve

> find /home/cgallardo/backups/local/mysql -mtime -7 -type f

Comment: Gracias, solo una duda el -mtime es "-7" o "+7"

Comment: Si no me equivoco es menos de 7 dias o mas de 7 dias, creo que te es mas correcto +7 en tu caso